# Как можно сравнить два числа с плавающей точкой?

Tags: php, float, compare

Мне необходимо произвести сравнения по типу

`if ($a + $b < $c) { /*true*/ } else { /*false*/ }`

но так как все три переменных представляют собой числа с плавающей точкой с двумя знаками после запятой, сравнение делаю так:

`if ($a + $b - $c < -0.001) { /*true*/ } else { /*false*/ }`

Правильно делаю? Видел пример проверки на равенство тут: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.float.php, но примеров для проверки меньше/больше не нашёл.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.bccomp.php

Comment: @binliz да это хорошее решение, но что скажете по поводу мною написанного решения, оно верно?

Comment: Может я что-то недопонимаю, но почему не воспользоваться простым `floatval` ?

Comment: @phpBear вот тут информация в красном окошке почему нельзя напрямую сравнивать: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.float.php

Comment: @orel-22 мануалы я читал :) основная проблема `floatval` в сравнении чисел с основанием 10 т.е одним знаком после запятой - в задаче же сказано, что `$a`, `$b` и `$c` имеют два знака после запятой так, что `floatval` теоретически должен подходить

Comment: Мне кажется справа значение с плюсом наоборот должно быть. Хотя смотря что вы хотите от этого сравнения.

Comment: Всё верно. Ещё есть вариант использования только с целыми числами. Умножьте число на сто. Округляйте, и целые числа спокойно сравнивайте. `$ac = floor ( $a * 100 + 0.5 ) ;`, `if ($ac + $bc < $cc)`

Comment: @AlexGlebe , подскажите, пожалуйста, для чего 0.5 в в примере?

Comment: Цена 0.30 будет в компьютерных регистрах на самом деле 0.29..99 . И `floor($a * 100)` приведёт к неожиданному числу 29. По-этому `floor( .. + 0.5 );` даёт правильное округление. Или, что ещё проще, можно использовать `round($a * 100)` == `floor($a * 100 + 0.5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Ваши переменные действительно по условиям задачи имеют точность не более двух знаков после запятой, то все прекрасно работает как говорится `из коробки`, по крайней мере на `php v7.4.10`. Так что думаю, что делать сравнение как в Вашем варианте -  излишне.

```php
<?php
$a = 0.11;
$b = 0.12;
$c = 0.24;

echo '$a = '.$a."\n";
echo '$b = '.$b."\n";
echo '$c = '.$c."\n";

echo '1) $a + $b < $c = ';

if ( $a + $b < $c ) { 
 echo "true\n";
} else { echo "false\n"; }

echo '2) $a + $b < $c = ';
if ( floatval($a) + floatval($b) < floatval($c) ) { 
 echo "true\n";
} else { echo "false\n"; }
```

Результат

```
$a = 0.11
$b = 0.12
$c = 0.24
1) $a + $b < $c = true
2) $a + $b < $c = true
```

Comment: Да, точно, не обратил внимание на "основание 10"